# how to select file upload in tosca automation tool

Tags: tosca

Is it possible to automate a test which selects a file from your computer and upload it online? I have also tried by giving the path in Openfile dialog, still it is not working. I will appreciate it some one can throw light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can share what specifically isn't working?
I do not think it is a general problem - people have done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to automate file upload in tosca i have done that in I.E follow the simple steps to achieve the desired results.

1. Scan the section where we provide path in window pop of upload file.Use identify by index if possible else go with any other solid property according to your application in my case i used identify by index.
2. Move that scanned module in your test cases and then provide the exact path where you want to upload file and keep as INPUT

I hope it helps it works for me cheers!!